# dark mode changing two pictures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm facing this problem, I have two pictures but only one of them is changing on click to the inverted version...is there some problem in code, or?

```
<script>
    const toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
    const body = document.body;

    // Function to toggle between dark and light mode
    function toggleDarkMode() {
        body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
        // Save the user's preference to localStorage
        var imgElement = document.getElementById("image");
        var imgElement = document.getElementById("svg");
        if (body.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
            localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
            toggleButton.textContent = 'Light';
            imgElement.src = "task2invert.png";
            imgElement.src = "logoinvert.svg";

        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'disabled');
            toggleButton.textContent = 'Dark';
            imgElement.src = "task2.png";
            imgElement.src = "logo.svg";
        }
    }

    // Check localStorage for the user's preference and set the initial mode
    if (localStorage.getItem('darkMode') === 'enabled') {
        body.classList.add('dark-mode');
        toggleButton.textContent = 'Light';
    }
```

whole codes here: [3 codes in total](https://p.bendo.dev/lakezisage.http)

I am not an expert for JavaScript, so if I only knew what's wrong and what have I changed...

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you provided the HTML and CSS so that we could get a better picture of what's happening. The first thing I see, however, is that you are setting a single variable twice, which is not something you should do. Perhaps the second time you could name the variable `svgElement` instead of `imgElement`. Then you, and the JavaScript interpreter, could tell them apart.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without the CSS and HTML you're using, answering this question is a bit tricky to do without making assumptions.

The first thing I would suggest is to make distinct variable names for the different things you're trying to work with. It looks like you're using the same name for multiple variables. This looks like it may be your main issue:

```
<script>
const toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
const body = document.body;

// Function to toggle between dark and light mode
function toggleDarkMode() {
    body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
    // Save the user's preference to localStorage
    var imgElement = document.getElementById("image");
    var svgElement = document.getElementById("svg");
    if (body.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
        localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
        toggleButton.textContent = 'Light';
        imgElement.src = "task2invert.png";
        svgElement.src = "logoinvert.svg";

    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'disabled');
        toggleButton.textContent = 'Dark';
        imgElement.src = "task2.png";
        svgElement.src = "logo.svg";
    }
}

// Check localStorage for the user's preference and set the initial mode
if (localStorage.getItem('darkMode') === 'enabled') {
    body.classList.add('dark-mode');
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Light';
}
```

I changed your variable names which handle svg's to svgElement, but you can use any variable name you'd like.

Comment: yeah, I tried that one, it didn´t work for me, only the other photo worked for a change...

Comment: Would you be able to provide your CSS and html to help shed more light on the issue you're having? I'd be able to assist better if I could see your code.

Comment: yes, i deited the post,i added the codes threre,,but here they are https://p.bendo.dev/exerafibib.php-template
and here is the page
https://mmicuch.mojawebka.eu/?id=assignments

it makes the changes perfectly in "assignments" but in "task2" you have to refresh the page to change it